# Capture event and dispatch it in Osmdroid

Tags: c#, osmdroid

*I explain the problem :* I have around 600 markers in the map, and they all have a click listener to display a new layout.

But my application need to place a custom marker specificaly if we tap on the map (user fictive location).

So it looks simple but it's not. I catch all the event with

```
public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
```

and look if it's a gesture or a tap, if it is a tap, a custom marker will appear on the map. But **how to check** if there is already a marker on the map (*behind the tap*), and then show the marker information instead of fictive location ?

I saw that we can click on the map

```
MapView myMap = FindViewById<MapView> (Resource.Id.mapview);

myMap.Click += delegate {

// don't work

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really using osmdroid (in Java, not in C#), then OSMBonusPack [Markers](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0) and [MapEventsReceiver](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5) should perfectly fit your need.

Comment: I use osmdroid with Xamarin (C# cross-platform). Thanks, it worked this way !